# Handle application states (starting/stopping) not activity states

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, application-lifecycle

I'm working on my 1st Android app and wondering how to handle activation/deactivation/starting/stopping globally, not on Activity level.

This great article shows states transition for Activities:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Is there something similar for Application states?

For example at iOS and Windows Phone app there is clear app states separated from activities (views, controllers, whatever).

I'm asking because I want to perform certain operations only once per app loading/exiting not with every activity starting/stopping

Comment: I don't really know of a built-in way to do that, but if there is one, it would be nice to know.  I believe you will have to create your own class that watches for leaving the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is There is **Simply No Direct method** to do this

rather than in Application Class you can catch these events

```
@Override
public void onLowMemory()
{
    super.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onTerminate()
{
    super.onTerminate();
}
```

So you will have to handle it  in all the Activities you will be having

the following methods

- onResume()
- onStart()
- onRestart()
- onPause()
- onDestroy()

You will have to implement in all Activity to handle for all application

### A suggesstion

You can have some Variable in Application class to save application state

say create a variable like

```
public static boolean isPaused;
```

and set it from all activity on state change

Answer (score 2):

The question you're asking is applicable for iOS and Windows but not really for Android.

Android doesn't really have a concept of an application as an object, although there's an Application class. Instead, an app is a loose collection of Activities. There are many good reasons for this state of affairs; for example, it supports fast app switching and easy interaction between Activities of different apps.

The best way to coordinate your "app" so that one Activity doesn't try to do something that's already been done is to use SharedPreferences to store app state. Nearly every other way of doing it is less preferred. Even if the system kills off your entire app, SharedPreferences will maintain the current state. The Application object won't.

Also, Android is based on pausing and resuming. An Activity or activities are created, pause, and resume. They may be destroyed, but that's an extreme case. A corollary to this is that apps should not have an exit button; there's no need for one. I sometimes see apps that have one, but what they're really trying to do is shut down a background Service or process. The best way to do that is to have an affordance that says "Sleep" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Have all activities inherit from the same hierarchy and put whatever you want in OnCreate, OnPause, OnResume, OnStop, OnDestroy and call the super where applicable.

Example

**Parent**

```
IamTheParentActivity : Activity

protected void onCreate()
{
setApplicationState(ApplicationState.Running);
}

protected void onPause()
{
setApplicationState(ApplicationState.Paused);
}

private void setApplicationState(Enum ApplicationState)
{
//Some Application Level Variable
Application.State = ApplicationState
}
```

**Children**

```
IamTheChild : IamTheParentActivity

protected void override onCreate()
{
base.OnCreate;
do other stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks, I want to load app state whenever application is activated(resumed). If I put this login in super class it will be called every time I navigating to new Activity. Otherwise if I put this logic for the first Activity I could lose some date when user reactivates my app on say the second Activity.

Comment: I am unclear about your statement. If you want your logic to be called every time you app resumes put the state logic in onresume of the super class and update the application level variable holding state. If there are circumstances ie a second activity in which you dont want to change state just use some logic to determine that within your application state handling method.